# Alter table schema while loading mysqldump in MySql

Tags: sql, mysql

I want to load `mysqldump` file into a server.

while loading dump , I want to change few column values and update schema.

for example for `guid` column we gave `varchar(100)` so now I want to change into `binary(16)` that means I need change in table schema and table values.

can I do this changes while loading dump file into new server.

Thanks

Comment: If the backup consists of sql commands, then just change the sql commands in the file and execute the modified file.

Comment: Its a huge file around 50 gb . I can't open it on my machine

Comment: Why do you want to do it during loading the dump? Cant you just alter the tables afterwards?

Answer (score 1):

No, basically you can't do anything WHILE loading dump. As mentioned in comments, you have two options:

1. Edit SQL in dump
2. Load dump and after that execute a script
   with needed fixes.

If you have access to initial database, you can produce another dump with needed changes.

Comment: @Rams yes, sure, you can load edited dump. Maybe "while" was a confusing part to me - dump editing, obviously,  must be done before loading dump to database.

Comment: thanks for your comment but what is the best way option 1 or option 2. And my db size is around 400 gb so my sql file will be huge. I think I can't open it on my machine

Comment: I'd vote for second option because changing something in huge dumps is possible source of errors. Just upload your dump on the server, import it into mysql and perform changing. Changing script may take long to execute due to size of your DB, but loading dump will take much more time anyway.